# If não busca por valor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Tem um trecho no meu programa que procura por uma string específica para atribuir um valor a alguma variável. Porém eu não estou conseguindo rodar esses parâmetros dentro do "If"... A depuração passa direto por isso.

```
//if (valor == "Datasul")
                    if (valor.Contains("Datasul"))
                    {
                        t1.ObsRecurso = model.ObsDatasul;
                    }
                    else if (valor.Contains("Protheus"))
                    {
                        t1.ObsRecurso = model.ObsProtheus;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        t1.ObsRecurso = "";
                    }

                    ListaRecursos.Add(t1);

                }
```

Tentei fazer essa busca tanto com `if (valor == "Datasul")` quanto `valor.Contains("Datasul"))`, porém em nenhum dos casos o programa entra nessa condicional.

**@EDIT**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tentou usar Equals?

Comment: `if (valor.Equals("Datasul"))`

Comment: Hudson, qual o valor da variável `valor`?

Comment: @viana Em C# isso não faz diferença, a não ser que o operador/método seja reescrito.

Comment: @LINQ A variável está retornando o valor correto. Editei o post com um GIF ilustrativo.

Answer (score 1):

Hudson, verifica se da seguinte forma funciona:

```
valor.ToUpper().Trim().Contains("PROTHEUS")
```

Ou

```
valor.ToUpper().Trim().Equals("PROTHEUS")
```

Caso contrário, verifica se realmente essa string está com o valor corrento, depurando ou com algum log.

Comment: Não tive sucesso em nenhuma das duas manerias. Ele simplesmente não executa a condicional. https://i.imgur.com/g1JsY95.gif

Comment: Com contains também não funcionou?

Comment: Não. Nenhum dos dois caminhos funcionaram